# Integrating with QB Desktop products

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I wrote a QB integration a few years ago that uses the Web Connector to read and write data to and from QB desktop products. It works well but I am not in love with the Web Connector.

I am tasked with setting up another QB integration. I was hoping to avoid using the Web Connector this time. There are a few reasons why I am trying to avoid the Web Connector but the main reason is I would like to make this integration work with both Desktop and Online versions of QB.

Is it possible to use the Intuit Sync Manager to sync the company data up to Intuit and then just use the standard Online APIs to connect to that company file? I have done some testing and I can connect to QB Online via the Online APIs but I cannot seem to get it to see the synced company files.

Any help with this would be great. Just looking for a little direction here.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For QBO, of-course, you can use QBO REST APIs(V3) API. 
Ref - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi

But for QBD, QBSDK and web-connector is still the only approach. 
QBD V2 and V3 REST APIs are already deprecated.

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0250_qb
- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0250_qb/0010_get_oriented/0080_quickbooks_web_connector

[FAQ](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0058_faq#Does_QuickBooks_API_support_QuickBooks_Desktop_and_QuickBooks_Online.3F)

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the help. I guess I am just confused what the Intuit Sync Manager is used for then? For some reason I thought I could use that and then just connect to the company file that it syncs. I guess I am wrong but I am still not sure what the point of the Sync Manager is. Thanks again

Comment: SM used to help to upload QBD companys file's data from desktop to cloud and also to download cloud data to your desktop(company file). And using QBD REST APIs ( V2/V3 both are deprecated now), you could have interacted with your synced cloud data. As QBD APIs are deprecated, so you can't take this approach anymore. To get details on SM, please refer - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/95_legacy/qbd_v2/qbd_v2_reference/0300_sync_manager
Thanks

Comment: Thanks again Manas. I see what you are saying but I know there are apps out there that use the Sync Manager to pull QBD data out and then integrate it with their web apps. Is this just not supported for new apps? Are those apps going to have to change the way they work? I am just trying to figure this all out. Thanks

Comment: Correct. No new apps can take that approach. Existing app may/may not use their old approach. But for new app, qbsdk is the only solution. You can refer this migration guideline (https://developer.intuit.com/blog/2013/12/19/2014-roadmap-and-migration-dates-for-existing-developers).

Comment: Thanks Manas. Makes sense. I also found this article that helped me understand what is going on - http://www.sleeter.com/blog/2013/11/quickbooks-software-integration/

Comment: In most of my projects it has worked better to build my own connector on the desktop, and then implement more generic web services on the server (i.e. not QB-specific). Of course it depends on the situation, but I've always thought it a bit awkward to build a SOAP web service that conforms to a standard dictated by the client (web connector).