# Need clarification on QuickBooks Desktop integration with Sync Manager vs Web Connector

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

From what I understand, Intuit is no longer allowing proprietary integrations with QuickBooks Desktop editions through the Sync Manager and only allowing apps that are put into the marketplace.  Is this really the case?  If so, is there a timeline for when they will start allowing this?  Also, it seems that the supported objects for desktop editions is way behind those supported for the online edition.  Will these be available any time soon (I.e. reports such as balance sheet, profit/loss, budget, etc.)?

I ask because we have been using the web connector for a couple of years now and it is not built for the type of use we need.  To be specific, we are a franchising company that has a hosted QB solution for each of our franchises.  We then pull data and pass jobs to and from our proprietary POS application through the web connector.  We run into all sorts of problems with multiple web connectors being open on the same system trying to connect to different files and a host of other issues.  Because of this, we are hoping that a more reliable integration can be developed through the Sync Manager.

Comment: Couple of things that may be worth noting - Sync Manager was almost a clone of the Web Connector regarding how connections work. So based on what you've said so far, you'd likely run into the same problems with Sync Manager as you're running into now. With that said -- the Web Connector works just fine in franchise type scenarios where multiple Web Connectors and company files are open. Would highly recommend you take a close look at your implementation, as it might be the culprit vs. the Web Connector itself. Without more details, hard to say much more than that.

Answer (score 0):

- From what I understand, Intuit is no longer allowing proprietary integrations with QuickBooks Desktop editions through the Sync Manager and only allowing apps that are put into the marketplace. Is this really the case?

Correct. QBD integration with SM and V3/V2 REST endpoints are not supported. 
Apps.com is the mainly the SaaS marketplace ( mainly focused on QBO). 
No new integration using QBD V3 can be created.

- Also, it seems that the supported objects for desktop editions is way behind those supported for the online edition. Will these be available any time soon (i.e. reports such as balance sheet, profit/loss, budget, etc.)?

  V3 QBD APIs are already marked as deprecated. There will not be any development on this.
  Ref - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0058_faq#Does_QuickBooks_API_support_QuickBooks_Desktop_and_QuickBooks_Online.3F

Please refer the following thread on similar topic.

[Integrating with QB Desktop products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22641754/integrating-with-qb-desktop-products)

Thanks